# Jquery UI autocomplete IE 7 issue

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using jquery UI autocomplete. It works in all other browsers FF, Chrome etc except IE7. Works for higher versions of IE as well but IE7 gives the below error:

```
SCRIPT3: Member not found.
jquery.min.js, line 2 character 30636
```

This is my function:

```
   $('input.autocomplete').each( function() {
   var $input = $(this);

   // Set-up the autocomplete widget.
   var serverUrl = $input.data('url');

$(this).autocomplete({
   source: function( request, response ) { 

    var countrySelect = $("#countrySelect").val();

 if($input.attr('id') == 'searchJobPostalCode'){

    countrySelect = $("#searchJobCountrySelect").val();

    }else if($input.attr('id') == 'searchPeoplePostalCode'){

    countrySelect = $("#searchUserCountrySelect").val();

    }
    $.ajax({
                url: serverUrl,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term,
                    countrySelect: countrySelect
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                        $input.removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );
                        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        if(typeof item.companyName != 'undefined'){
                            return {
                                label: item.companyName,
                                value: item.companyName,
                                id: item.companyID
                            }
                    }

                        if(typeof item.locationId != 'undefined'){
                            return {
                                label: item.postalCode +','+item.placeName+','+item.adminName1+','+item.countryCode,
                                value: item.postalCode +','+item.placeName+','+item.adminName1+','+item.countryCode,
                                postalCode: item.postalCode,
                                city: item.placeName,
                                state: item.adminName1,
                                country: item.countryCode
                            }
                    }


                        //to show user alias autocomplete on compose message
                        if(typeof item.userAlias != 'undefined'){
                                    var label1 = item.userAlias;
                                    if(typeof item.city != 'undefined'){
                                        label1 = label1+','+item.city;
                                    }
                                    if(typeof item.state != 'undefined'){
                                        label1 = label1+','+item.state;
                                    }
                                    if(typeof item.country != 'undefined'){
                                        label1 = label1+','+item.country;
                                    }

                            return {
                                label: item.userAlias,
                                userAlias: item.userAlias
                            }
                    }

                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,cacheLength:0,keyDelay:900,
        select: function( event, ui ) {

        $("#companyId").val(ui.item.id);

        if(typeof ui.item.userAlias != 'undefined'){
            $(".toUser").val(ui.item.userAlias);
        }

        if(typeof ui.item.postalCode != 'undefined'){
                $("#postalCode").val(ui.item.postalCode);
                $("#city").val(ui.item.city);
                $("#state").val(ui.item.state);
                $("#country").val(ui.item.country);


                    if($input.attr('id') == 'searchJobPostalCode'){

                                $("#searchPostalCodeJobsSearch").val(ui.item.postalCode);
                                $("#searchCityJobsSearch").val(ui.item.city);
                                $("#searchStateJobsSearch").val(ui.item.state);
                                $("#searchCountryJobsSearch").val(ui.item.country);

                    }else if($input.attr('id') == 'searchPeoplePostalCode'){

                                $("#searchPostalCodePeople").val(ui.item.postalCode);
                                $("#searchCityPeople").val(ui.item.city);
                                $("#searchStatePeople").val(ui.item.state);
                                $("#searchCountryPeople").val(ui.item.country);

                    }


        }
        },
                change: function( event, ui ) {
                if($(this).attr('id') !='companyName'){
                        if ( ui.item == null) {
                                valid = false;
                            }else{
                                valid = true;
                            }
                            if ( !valid ) {
                                // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                $( this ).val( "" );
                                select.val( "" );
                                input.data( "autocomplete" ).term = "";
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );

        }
    });

});
```

I tried to debug and it errors out at line : `$(this).autocomplete({`

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try renaming your `input` class to something other than `autocomplete`. Maybe `input.ac` or something. And, it seems like `$(this).autocomplete({` could be `$input.autocomplete({`

Comment: Thanks. This did not solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with my OS. I had installed Windows 8 consumer preview and was running IE using dev tools in IE7 compatibility. It works in windows 7. thanks.

Comment: Seems to be the same for IE10 running in IE7 mode on Win7. (Win8 has IE10 bundled right?) However, it works fine for real IE7 running on VirtualPC.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that one of the scripts is not loading properly. This happened to me once, with jquery and IE 7. Here's how I solved the issue:

In the HTML, BEFORE all of your script tags, add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script><!--this is here because of an IE bug-->
```

When I included that line before my tag for jquery.min.js, the problem went away.

IE7 is a frustration.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved with change ui version. Now I use 1.9.1.custom.min.js (before was jquery UI 1.8) and it work with IE7 compatibility. I use jquery v1.7.2